# Auto canceling orders that go into payment gateways, but never come back

Tags: payment-gateway, external

I have this issue.

Sometimes orders go into gateways I built but are lost in the process. They just never come back with either failure or success. Is there a way I can cancel them if they are away for too long and don't come back to be processed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the best way to do this would be to give them a custom status on checkout with those gateways, such as "Awaiting Gateway Response".  Then have a scheduled CRON job each night that checks the current time against the time created for all orders with that status, and if it matches a threshold of X days/hours, change the order status and save.

Comment: Also we need increment the qty when an order is cancelled. So setting for this must be defined in the System > Configuration > Inventory section.